jq manipulate object where field matches regex
I need to delete a field .xxx from an object at any depth of the tree where another field .myfield matches a regex.
I know how to match a precise content:
walk(if type == "object" and .myfield == "my content" then del(.xxx) else . end)'

I know about the regex filter
select(.myfield | test(my regexp))

How can I convert that filter to a boolean condition for use in the if clause?

Please replace your pseudocode with a [mre] -- something actually runnable so people can test their answers. That means a real regex, sample input data including both content that does match and content that doesn't, a jq expression using field names that actually exist in that data, and sample/expected output.

(...if you want to crib from the sample data I generated for purposes of making my answer testable, by all means feel free to copy it into the question).

You can use (.myfield | test("my regexp")) in a conditional just as you can use .myfield == "my content".
Thus:
jq -c '
  walk(if type == "object" and
          (.myfield | type) == "string" and
          (.myfield | test("my regexp"))
       then del(.xxx)
       else . end)
' <<'EOF'
{
  "structure": {
    "test-match": {
      "myfield": "content that matches my regexp",
      "xxx": "this should be deleted"
    },
    "test-nomatch": {
      "myfield": "content that DOES NOT match the active expression",
      "xxx": "this should not be deleted"
    },
    "test-invalid": {
      "state": "no myfield exists at all",
      "xxx": "this should not be deleted"
    }
  }
}
EOF

...properly emitting as output:
{
  "structure": {
    "test-match": {
      "myfield": "content that matches my regexp"
    },
    "test-nomatch": {
      "myfield": "content that DOES NOT match the active expression",
      "xxx": "this should not be deleted"
    },
    "test-invalid": {
      "state": "no myfield exists at all",
      "xxx": "this should not be deleted"
    }
  }
}


@peak, updated accordingly, thanks -- that's indeed more robust
